# Setting up database role membership in sql server through t-sql or stored procedure for sql login user

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a login using sql authentication and assigned one database to this login and created user for this login.Now I would like to set database role membership through T-sql or stored procedures.Can any one please guide me.
If I use EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'Domain\User' it will set membership for user not for login.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuyRj.png)
Here i have attached image

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a login to a database role. Logins are server principals, users are database principals.

If you do it from the GUI (as per your image), SSMS will detect if you have an existing user mapped to that login. If you do, it will then run

```
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [domain\user]
```

If not, it will first create a user with the same login name, then add that user to the DB role. If you tried to add a login to a DB role via TSQL, it will fail.

Comment: Thanks for your information.I have one more question can we set Owned schemas for a sql user through TSQL or stored procedure?

Comment: ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::myschema TO roopesha  Just remember that schemas are database objects so can only be owned by users, not logins.